# Like service database organization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, nosql

Say I want to build a Like Service that supports multiple likable entities: photos, comments, users or whatever. The list is open-ended. I don't feel confident in this matter and my questions are:

1) How relational database engines suite my needs? I would have one common like entity (like_id, user_id), and multiple pivot entities: like_photo (id, like_id, photo_id), like_video  (id, like_id, video_id) where the like_id field in pivot tables is a foreign key that references to the common like table allowing to idenify the user who liked and possibly other info such as like timestamp etc.

2) Do I rather use some kind of nosql database for that purpose (have no experience in nosql at all)?

2.1) Is it possible to have a reliable cross-database reference (RMDBS - nosql database)

Answer (score 0):

You're giving us very little to go on - and this question may descend into debate and opinion.

But I'll give it a go - based on the very little information you provide...

If all you have to do is create, read, update and delete the fact that users like objects, then yes, a relational database is just the ticket.

```
users
----------
userID
....


Objects
----------
objectID
URL
objectType
....


Likes
----------
UserID
ObjectID
```

You may, of course, need to store more information about your "objects". That's where you're likely to run into trouble - relational database are not elegant if you have to store polymorphic data types. You can Google that (I've seen and answered several questions on that on SO).

Whether NoSQL is "better" here is purely down to the use cases you intend to support. You'd need to provide more context.

Comment: thanks for the answer! It was more a conceptual question, this is probably a wrong place to ask. Anyway, the context is a Laravel/MySql-based application. There is a few tables that hold the content (posts, comments, photos, videos), and I basically want a distinct service that provides the liking functionality. It must be able to quickly extract likes for any any individual object/collection of objs that support likes along with the related info, it also should be able to aggregate data about likes and compute some statistics. Sorry, I'm not sure if this message clarifies anyhting.